# I want to send the 'id' to coldfusion variable to perform some query

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I am having a problem sending the id value to coldfusion variable in other page.

```
<!--first page-->
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#d1").mouseenter(function(e) {
    var id = this.id;
    .ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'jobdetail.cfm?jobdt=' + id,
      data: {
        jobdt: 'id'
      }
    });
  });
})
```

```
<!--jobdetail.cfm-->

<cfset var1 = url.jobbt>
<cfquery>  
    select XXX......
</cfquery>
```

Comment: You have to get id out of the ColdFusion world and get it into the Javascript world. There are a lot of ways to do this. Perhaps a hidden field. Perhaps a `data-` attribute. Or perhaps you come from a Javascript background, but Javascript isn't even something you need at all.

Comment: The phrase "having a problem" is very ambiguous.  What actually happens when you run the code and what were you expecting to happen instead? Also, if that's your real code there are several issues 1) The name of the variable in your .cfm script `url.jobbt` doesn't match the variable names in the ajax call `jobdt` 2) Putting quotes around the variable name here `{ jobdt: 'id'}` submits the literal characters "id" - NOT the *value* of the `id` variable. 3) Why are you submitting the `jobdt` parameter in both the URL and as a POST variable?

Comment: As written, it's unclear what problem you're having with the code, so this question is likely to be [closed as "unclear"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please take a moment to read [Ask] and then update your question with more details, error messages, etc..

Answer (score 1):

You’ve got a couple things to fix:

First, no need to add the ID to the url. Send it in the data as follows (notice that I removed the quotes around id):

```
<!--first page-->
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#d1").mouseenter(function(e) {
    var id = this.id;
    .ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'jobdetail.cfm ',
      data: {
        jobdt: id
      }
    });
  });
})
```

Second, since you are sending a POST request, you need to access the ID from the Form scope, not the URL scope, as follows:

```
<cfset var1 = Form.jobdt>
```

Comment: It's way OT, but also don't forget to use `cfparam` and other sanitation and validation in your CF file. You definitely don't want to consume content from untrusted sources (like FORMs and URLs).